# reinstalling on mirrored SCSI drives

Tags: windows, windows-xp

when reinstalling windows Xp professional on a dell Precision 670 with SCSI drives i get the error setup did not find any harddisk connected to your machine,how do I get setup to recognise the operating system

Answer (score 3):

You will need the storage driver for that controller. When you start the installer of the OS, it will ask you to press F6 if you have drivers. A little further down the setup, it will then ask for the disk containing them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the driver for the disk controller during setup. If you have a floppy drive you can put the driver onto a diskette and press "F6" at the appropriate time when setup is starting. If not then you'll probably want to use a tool like [nLite](http://www.nliteos.com/) to build a custom Windows XP setup CD w/ the driver on the disc.